# How do I automatically update Grafana dashboards (and datasources) in the Docker Image from the exported JSON?

Tags: bash, docker, grafana

I am attempting to update Grafana dashboards/data-sources automatically inside a Grafana Docker image using the exported relevant JSON which is stored (and routinely updated) in Github/Bitbucket.

E.g.:

1. Docker image running Grafana
2. The Dockerfile adds a Bash script which pulls from a Git source,
3. The script then copies the JSON files into the relevant directories (/etc/grafana/provisioning/datasource + /dashboards).
4. Graphs and datasources are updated without the manual intervention (other than updating the JSON stored in Github or Bitbucket).

I have EXEC'ed into the Grafana docker image and Grafana runs on a very basic linux system, therefore practically no commands can be used i.e., git, wget, apt.

Would I be silly in thinking I should create a Dockerfile from the base Debian image, running an apt update and installing git inside. Then somehow running Grafana and the script inside that image?

please feel free to ask for more information.

Comment: `no commands can be used i.e., git, wget, apt` ? so install them? It runs on  debian. `apt-get update && apt-get install git wget`. `apt update and installing git inside` - that's normal. `Then somehow` - create a dockerfile, add a `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install && apt-get autoremove` and build that dockerfile that's all. If the ENTRYPOINT stays the same, you still will run grafana. Btw. [grafana dockerfile](https://github.com/grafana/grafana-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile).

Comment: If you've `git cloned/pulled` the latest updates into the provisioning folder recreating the container will get a fresh copy of Grafana provisioned as specified. However, you may want to preserve any existing settings, users, etc. (lost on re-create) in which case you would need use docker volumes to map corresponding Grafana folders from the container to folders on the host machine, as mentioned by  Kamil Cuk. And then you can update files directly there and just restart instead of recreate. 
Or `ssh` into the container and use the Grafana CLI https://grafana.com/docs/administration/cli/

Answer (score 1):

Consider a simpler approach that uses docker volumes:

- `grafana` container uses docker volumes for `/etc/grafana/provisioning/datasource + /dashboards`
- Those docker volumes are shared with other docker container, that you create.
- Your docker container runs an incoming [webhook](https://github.com/adnanh/webhook) server, publicly available.
- If that webhook is triggered, then your script runs.
- That script `git pull`s the changes from your repo and `copies the JSON files into the relevant directories`. The "relevant directories" are those shared docker volumes between your docker and grafana docker.
- You register a webhook to be executed in the github repo on each push on master.

The whole process is automated and looks like this:

- You push on master to your github repo with the relevant sources
- Your docker with incoming webhook server is pocked by github
- Your docker executes a script
- That script git pulls the github repo and copies the JSON files into the shared folders
- If you need ex. to restart the grafana container from that script, you can mount docker socket `-v /var/run/docker.sock` and execute docker commands from inside the container.

Comment: so the docker container that runs the hook is different than the Grafana container?
I somewhat get the approach but it's a bit unclear tbh

Comment: Yes, exactly yes, that's the point. Docker is build just for that - so you can separate different parts of your system. There is little to no need to make changes to grafana container.

Comment: Sure!
But at the same time docker was also built to reuse and expand base images so there's nothing wrong with making a self-updating Grafana container.